# PHP performance benchmarking between Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, windows-server-2012-r2, microsoft

I'm trying to look around for any reliable PHP performance benchmarking test between Windows Server vs Linux. To be specific, this is what I'm going after:-

PHP 7.2
Windows Server 2012
Linux Ubuntu

I have read in various online resources proclaiming that Linux is inherently superior in running PHP than Windows. But, I'd like to get some numbers to back up this claim.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I have read in various online resources proclaiming that Linux is
>   inherently superior in running PHP than Windows.

Anyone making a claim about "inherent superiority" about a certain platform's performance, without data, is being dishonest or biased. Especially when you might be running the same application on the same processor, just a different OS.  Both Linux and Windows are optimized for performance, even if their implementation is different down to the kernel architecture.

Performance is dependent on your specific application environment and workload, plus many other variables.

Find out yourself which platform you like. Deploy your application in production on both Linux and Windows. Pick one based on the ease of development and operations, in addition to any performance criteria.

Comment: I concur with your thought about claims being backed up by cold, hard facts and data. The reason behind this is to win support from a client to stick with our proposal  to use the Linux implementation of PHP over Windows (their choice). Having said that, performance is only one aspect of the equation. We are looking at costs as well as the expertise area of the support team as well. Cheers!